# A tiny question: The little big family

Tags: logical-deduction, family

In a family, there are the following human members:
Grandfather, grandmother, father, mother, son, daughter.

All family members are inside a single room now.

Question:
What is the minimum amount of people inside the room now?

Comment: You can always try [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_%28film%29)

Comment: There needs to be some clarification on the the permissibility of more lateral answers involving time travel, hermaphrodite(s), and incestuous marriage and/or relations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Three people
>  Consider Anna, Bill and Carl.
>  Imagine a land where it is allowed to marry your own children
>  Anna is Bill's **daughter**. Therefore Bill is her **father**.
>  Anna marries Bill.
>  They both get a **son** Carl.
>  So Bill is Carl's father and **grandfather**.
>  And Anna is Carl's **mother**
>  But, Anna is also Carl's (step-)**grandmother** because she is married to his grandfather

Comment: (step-) grandmother is not a grandmother at all.

Answer (score 18):

There are at least

> 4 people.
>
>   Consider a couple Anna and Bill. They have a son Carl, who has a daughter Dora.
>
>   Then,
>   - Anna is a **grandmother** to Dora
>   - Bill is a **grandfather** to Dora
>   - Bill is a **father** to Carl (and Carl is a **father** to Dora)
>   - Anna is a **mother** to Carl
>   - Carl is a **son** to Anna and Bill
>   - Dora is a **daughter** to Carl
>
>  You can't have less than this. You need at least 3 generations in order for someone to be a grandparent, for a minimum of 3 people. But since we need both a grandmother and a grandfather, the eldest generation must have 2 people, for a total of four.

Comment: An interesting alternative is to span across four generations - great-grandmother, grandfather, mother, son.

Comment: @dmg you will need 5 then, as a rule of thumb, n+1 where n are the generations. You need a couple and then recursive incest over that couple. Works every time.

Comment: @bduran That's incorrect.  The four mentioned by dmg are sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. I understood that he wanted to modify the problem to get 2 of each, as in the original problem.

Answer (score 16):

> Two. A man: who is a grandfather, a father and a son; and a woman: who is a grandmother, a mother and a daughter.

Comment: The question states that "all family members are inside a single room."  Thus if a man is a grandfather to someone, that "someone" needs to be in the room.

Comment: A woman can be both a mother and a daughter (and a grandmother for that matter) at the same time. If such a woman is in the room, is she not there in all three of those capacities at once?

Comment: Yes, but if she is a grandmother, she necessarily has a granddaughter/grandson. If all family members are in the room, that granddaughter/grandson must be present as well.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Are you implying that you stop being a grandparent when your grandchild dies? I think that's a hard sell to some people.

Comment: @DrunkWolf - Yes, he is. Otherwise the question is trivial.

Comment: I'm with @Stacker here - nowhere in the question does it state that all (or, indeed, any) members are discrete entities. A reasonable assumption can be made that a single person cannot be two discrete genders simultaneously, but that's as far as that goes.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. However, if your grandchild dies, if his corpse is outside the room, not all family members are inside the room; if it is inside the room, it count as a people. Sorry for my poor English if corpses doesn't count as people in fact.

Comment: Yes, I'm with @UchihaJavara.  If you consider yourself a grandparent when your grandchild is dead, then that grandchild is still necessarily part of the family, and thus needs to be in the room.  If the grandchild is not part of the family, then you are obviously not a grandparent.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain But what's being proposed here is that the grandparent is him- or herself a grandchild (and a parent, and a son/daughter). Obviously it's Uchiha Javara's puzzle, so if that's not the answer they had in mind, that's fine, but the puzzle as written does not obviate this as a solution.

Comment: @question_asker The same applies in any case.  If the individual is a grandchild, there is necessarily a grandparent, who then ought to be present in the room.  If the individual is a parent, there is necessarily a child who must be present, etc.  If the *entire family* must be present in the room, then you can't claim that a single individual fulfills the criteria, unless that person is his own parent, grandparent, etc.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain 1) the question does not state that each title need be held by a unique person, and 2) if someone is, say, a grandfather, father, and a son (these last two are necessarily true of every male short of an ur-ancestor), then all of those things are present in the room whenever they are.  Again, this may not be the intended answer, but it is sufficient to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @UchihaJavara I don't get it, if you consider that dead ancestors or offsprings are part of the family, then the room should contain all the dead family members of anyone in the room. This is turning grim quite quickly

Comment: This raises the question - if the dead family members remains (ashes in urns, for instance) are in the room as well, do they count as people for the purposes of the question?

Answer (score 8):

If you allow for time-travel, the answer is ONE.

Read *[All you Zombies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies)*.  The protagonist of the story is hermaphroditic, and is his/her own father and mother, therefore also his/her own grandfather and grandmother.

Comment: No, he has no grandfather and grandmother.  He sprang from nothing in the time loop.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Technically, by the very definition of "grandparent": ["Grandparents are the parents of a person's father or mother"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandparent), one could apply a transitive closure on his relation with himself (he is his parent), and this solution will be valid for n-generations.

Answer (score 5):

- Any male human is a son
- Any female human is a daughter
- Any grandfather is a father
- Any grandmother is a mother

> So two people satisfy all the qualifications: a grandfather and a grandmother

Comment: The question states that "all family members are inside a single room."  Thus if a man is a grandfather to someone, that "someone" needs to be in the room.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Rather morbid, I'll admit, but if you just kill off the two most recent generations it works. Unless you want to argue that you stop being a (grand)parent just because your (grand)child died.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist See my [comment](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24024/a-tiny-question-the-little-big-family/24029?noredirect=1#comment73692_24026) on Stacker's answer.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I see what you mean: the answer hinges on whether you consider a man whose grandson died still a grandfather. I do, but I can see that other point of views may disagree

Answer (score 1):

Four. Here's one way:

> Alice has a son named Bob, who has a daughter named Carol. So, Alice is a mother and a grandmother, Bob is a father and a son, and Carol is a daughter and a granddaughter. They are all in the room. Then, Bob's paternal grandfather Dennis enters the room. So we have:
>
> Grandmother: Alice (to Carol)
>
> Grandfather: Dennis (to Bob)
>
> Father: Bob (to Carol)
>
> Son: Bob (to Alice)
>
> Daughter: Carol (to Bob)
>
> Granddaughter: Carol (to Alice)
>
> Grandson: Bob (to Dennis)

Four people, four generations, six roles, no two people filling the same roles, and no person filling the same role twice.

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on how you interpret some tricky relationships, there could be only **3** people in the room.
>  *Bill* is in the room, and is the **father** to *David* and **grandfather** to *Emma*. *Emma* is, obviously, the **daughter** of *David*. And *David* is the **son** of *Bill*.
>  Now, what you didn't know was that *Bill* used to be *Anna* before *gender-transitioning* from female to male, and *Anna* begot *Christina* through cloning.
>  Wait, who's *Christina*? Well, *David* used to be *Christina* before his own gender-transition, which is when (s)he gave birth to *Emma* - again through cloning.
>  So, *Bill* is also the **mother** of *David*, and is also the **grandmother** of *Emma*.

The modern age, folks: giving us new and interesting answers to age old puzzles!

> (I realize David doesn't really have to have switched genders, it could just be that Emma's mom is dead, but this way just feels more complete and less morbid - and also, if you go for cloning in the answer, why not go for it twice anyway!)

Okay, writing that out made me think of another possibility:

> Warning: potentially squicky. Again, **3** people, with tricky relationships that are subject to interpretation.
>  *Alice* gave birth to *Derek* through cloning, thus becoming the **mother** to *Derek* who is her **son**.
>  Then, *Alice* and *Derek* gave birth to *Eva*, who is thus their **daughter**. *Derek* is now a **father**. *Alice* is both **mother** and **grandmother** to *Eva*. 
>  Then, *Alice* chose to transition into *Bob*, thus becoming also the **grandfather** of *Eva*.
>  (What are you looking at me like that for? I warned ya! :)

Comment: This is an alternate universe where people are two genders simultaneously?

Comment: >! This is our own fine universe, and that's the "subject to interpretation" part. To my money, someone who carried the child to term and gave birth to her continues to have rights to the title "mother" (in addition to, and perhaps secondary to, the parent-title normally given to their current gender).

Comment: Well, if we're in our own universe, that's ... extremely uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a little bit more clarification on the question...

> It could simply be two grandparents. Both of them were born a son or daughter, then had their own children who had children. This means each member is a Grandfather, father, and son, or Grandmother, mother, and daughter all at once. If their children are (by some tragedy) all gone, then the "whole family" is in the room... (jeez that made me sad, just now)

Unless we're talking about a

> hermaphroditic grandparent, in which case, we could squeeze it down to 1. I feel like this isn't what the question was getting at, though...

Comment: Could I get a comment on the reason for the downvote, please?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess is it's because of the "all family members are in the room" requirement. The way most people are interpreting it (which I think is right) is that the grandparent and associated grandchild are in the room. So that while a grandfather is (obviously) a son of someone, they only "count" as a son for this problem if one of their parents is also in the room.

Answer (score 0):

Two.

Every man is a son to either parent. Thus Grandfather is a son, and by definition a father at the same time.
Every woman is a daughter to either parent. Grandmother is a daughter, and by definition, a mother at the same time.

Not knowing too much about genetics, it could possibly be **ONE**. If said individual was a chimera, who was hermaphroditic. Technically they could be both son and daughter, and grandmother, mother, grandfather, father if one half of the chimera shared the female genes, and genitalia, and the other half shared the male genes and genitalia. I know, its a convoluted answer, but....

Answer (score 0):

3-4

> If [Kourtney Kardashian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kourtney_Kardashian) decides to follow in her father's/mother's footsteps and becomes Kurtis Kardashian, then brings her son Mason and daughter Penelope to visit their grandmother [Caitlyn Jenner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caitlyn_Jenner), then you will have a biological grandfather, socially grandmother, biological mother, socially father, and son and daughter with only four people. If either Mason or Penelope choose to change their sex, you only need three.